# Rails pre-loading association with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have the following two models, joined separately by the following two joins models:

```
class Game
  has_many :game_plays
  has_many :game_views
end

class Person
  has_many :game_plays
  has_many :game_views
end

# Games that a Person has played
class GamePlay
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person
end

# Games that a Person has viewed
class GameView
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Given a specific `GamePlay`, I want to get the `GameView` for the same `Person`-`Game` combo, e.g:

```
game_play = GamePlay.first
game_view = GameView.find_by(game_id: game_play.game_id, person_id: game_play.person_id)
```

I also need to eager load that association.

---

I'd love to create an association between `GamePlay` and `GameView`, but nothing I've tried has worked so far.

**Attempt 1**

```
class GamePlay
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person

  has_one :game_view, -> (gp) { where(game_id: gp.game_id) }, foreign_key: :person_id, primary_key: :person_id
end
```

This works, but I can't `include` this:

```
GamePlay.includes(:game_view).first
# => ArgumentError: The association scope 'game_view' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes is not supported.
```

**Attempt 2**

```
class GamePlay
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person

  def game_view
    GameView.find_by(game_id: game_id, person_id: person_id)
  end
end
```

This obviously works, but I can't include this because it isn't defined as an association.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Rails 5.0.0
postgres 9.6.2

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class GamePlay < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :game_view, through: :person, source: :game_views
end

irb(main):002:0> GamePlay.includes(:game_view).find(2)
  GamePlay Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "game_plays".* FROM "game_plays" WHERE "game_plays"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = 1
  GameView Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "game_views".* FROM "game_views" WHERE "game_views"."person_id" = 1
=> #<GamePlay id: 2, game_id: 1, person_id: 1>

irb(main):008:0> GamePlay.find(2).game_view
  GamePlay Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "game_plays".* FROM "game_plays" WHERE "game_plays"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  GameView Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "game_views".* FROM "game_views" INNER JOIN "people" ON "game_views"."person_id" = "people"."id" WHERE "people"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<GameView id: 2, game_id: 1, person_id: 1>
```

Comment: This doesn't use the `game_id`.  It may before worth refactoring `GamePlay` and `GameView` into a polymorphic `PersonGame` model with a kind column.

Comment: I've been contemplating combining these tables for awhile now, for exactly this reason. I was hoping for an easier way than doing a refactor, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge, I solved this with a custom version of Rails preloader https://github.com/2rba/smart_preloader

The association is exactly as you described:

```rb
class GamePlay
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :person

  has_one :game_view, -> (gp) { where(game_id: gp.game_id) }, foreign_key: :person_id, primary_key: :person_id
end
```

and then explicitly call preloader as:

```
game_plays =GamePlay.all
ActiveRecord::SmartPreloader.(game_plays, ActiveRecord::CompositeKey.new(:game_view, [:game_id, :person_id])
```

that is pretty much the same as Rails default `GamePlay.preloads(:game_view)` behaviour which under the hood calls `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader`. The only difference preloader called explicitly, and preloader is slightly modified to support multikey and polymorphic associations.